# How to launch Steam games from Spotlight?

Tags: spotlight, steam

Is there a way to open Steam games directly from Spotlight?

Comment: Are you looking to bypass Steam.app and launch the installed games via Spotlight? Or are you just interested on locating the installed game’s files on disk?

Comment: Basically a shortcut for the executable - bypassing Steam.app in the sense that the executable will launch from Spotlight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your Steam games appear under Spotlight as follows:

1. Open **Steam.app**, go to Library, right click on the game entry and select **Create Desktop Shortcut** from the content menu. An alias for the game is created on the Desktop.

[image]

2. After the shortcut is created, it can be moved to any location on hard disk (as long as the location is indexed by Spotlight) and it will appear in Spotlight search results.

[image]